# Rx Scala - how to implement min time between emission

Tags: scala, observable

Can someone help me come up with a function that I can apply to an observable that will prevent emission from happening to quickly.

```
val later = Subject[Int]()
val combined = Observable.from(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) ++ later
combined.delayMinTime(1 second).doOnEach(...)
```

Normally this would emit 1-8 and then any time 'later' received an onNext. But what I would like is to emit 1-8, one every second and then any time later receives something,  as well as if it receives anything too quickly it delays each entry.
So in Rxmarbles - it would look like this

```
1 2 3 4               5 6          7 
▼
1   2   3   4         5    6       7
```

BTW if there is a better function name throw that in as well...

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for this being C#, but this is getting close:

```
var query = source.Publish(xs => xs.Window(() =>
{
    var n = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    return xs.Select((x, i) => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(System.Math.Max(1.0 + (double)i - DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(n).TotalSeconds, 1.0)))).Switch();
})).Select(xs => xs.Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)), (x, _) => x)).Merge();
```

It's still letting through some values with a gap less than 1.0 seconds, but it might be a good start to help you work out the kinks.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, interesting but I don't think that is the method that will work well in my application